# Highlight cell in a column if it does not contain specific value/text

Tags: excel, vba

I am still new to Macro and would like to get the following code running flawlessly with following conditions:

1) This vba to run from Column E2 until the last entry of the cell, i.e. Vba only runs on cells that have values/entries, do not run on blank cells.

2) Highlight the cell in yellow if that particular cell contains other word.

Below is the code I attempted:

```
'Highlight cell in Column E if it does not contain "USD"
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("E2:E").Value) Then
    With Range("E2:E")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
            Formula1:="=E2:E<>""USD"""
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .Color = vbYellow
        End With
    End With
    End If
```

Issues faced:

1) The first condition is not met.

2) I can only get the second condition worked if I add the specific cell range, for example:

```
'Highlight cell in Column E if it does not contain "USD"
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("E2:E").Value) Then
    With Range("E2:**E100**")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlNotEqual, _
            Formula1:="=E2:**E100**<>""USD"""
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .Color = vbYellow
        End With
    End With
    End If
```

Kindly need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to loop through the column for this

Comment: Calculate last cell row number, and then use `Range("E2:E" & LastRowNumber)`. Here in SO there are thousands of examples about calculating last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to loop through range and compare cell's text to you condition:

```
Sub CheckCellAndHighlight()
Dim CheckCell As range, CheckRange As range

Set CheckRange = range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)) ' Set the range you need to look through

For Each CheckCell In CheckRange
    If Not UCase(CheckCell.Text) = "USD" Then ' do not need to check whether the cell's value is text, just check whether it meets you particular condition
        CheckCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' color it if it meets the condition
    Else
        CheckCell.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The `Not CheckCell.Text = "USD"` means the same as `CheckCell.Text <> "USD"`.

**UPDATE**

As per comments, added two checks - one for checking the text's case because "usd" is not equal to "USD", and second - clear the color because the cell may have been colored previously.

Comment: Correct, but I think you should add a else with delete cell color. Otherwise there could be wrongly colored cells if you replace the data on the sheet

Comment: @Andreas well, yes, but that wasn't a task, one more thing that would added for sure is a text's case check, and there are some other possible checks depending on OPs task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to understand this line of code: `Set CheckRange = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))`

Comment: I believe it was a task from OP. See code `.FormatConditions.Delete` this deletes the colors before setting some to yellow. (if I understand it correct)

Comment: Why can't I use `Set CheckRange = Range("E2:E", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))` to get it worked? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @JeffCh That is the same as `range("E2:E<lastrow>")` No that wont work. you need `Set CheckRange = Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))` Notice the &

Comment: @JeffCh there is no difference, just more convenient for me to use `Cells(Row, Column)` instead of letters. You can't use it because of mistake - it should be written as `Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)` to work properly

Comment: The `Range("E2:E", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))` doesn't work because vba understands it as you're trying to union two different ranges - `"E2:E"` and `Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)`, due to comma between it. What you need to do - is to concatenate `"E2:E"` with the number of last row in this column. Last row is found with `Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` (don't forget the **.Row** because without it statement will return whole last cell, not it's row number) After, just concat it and you'll get the correct address for range: `"E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Thank you so much for your help! You helped me understand better, especially the .Row thingy. Marked as answer. :)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your help too! :)